# How do I dynamically set image height based on width in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component for rendering images. In a simplified form, it looks like this:

```
function Image(props) {
   return <img src="..." height={...} />
}
```

I wanted to set the height of the images dynamically based on some calculations (including the width of the image tag).
But to calculate the height of the image, I first need to wait for the image to load and then calculate the height.
But when the `render` method is called, the height is `null` because the image hasn't loaded yet.

- What is the correct way to set the height when the component renders and the image loads?
- As I wrote, to calculate the height of the image I use the width of the image - How I can access the DOM element (the image tag) in order to calculate the height based on the width of the element?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use an event handler for the image, specifically the `onLoad` event for images:

```
<img onLoad={...} />
```

The general form would be to have some value in state, such as the dynamic height like so, with some initial value:

```
this.state = {
  dynamicHeight: 0
};
```

Then, create an event handler to set these values on image load:

```
onLoad(image, imageElement) {
  this.setState({
    dynamicHeight: //do something to imageElement's width to calculate height
  });
}
```

Then use the values in you image element:

```
<img onLoad={...} height={this.state.dynamicHeight} />
```

This will rerender the component with the new dynamic height once it's done loading.